# How to get data from secure storage in another function?

Tags: flutter

How to get data from secure storage in any other function not in FutureBuilder.

```dart
Future<void> login() async {
  print('LOGGGGINNNNNNNNNNNN');
  print(read('TOKEN'));
}

Future read(String storageName) async {
  return await _storage.read(key: storageName);
}
```

Print result: Instance of 'Future'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

```
Future readStorage(String storageName) async {
  return await _storage.read(key: storageName);
}

 Future getToken() async {
  final _storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  await Future.sync(()  async =>  _token = await _storage.read(key: 'TOKEN'));
 }

Future<void> login() async {
  getToken().then((value){
  print(_token);
  if(_token == 'Not Authenticated' || _token == null)
    {
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticated = false;
      });
    }
  else {
    setState(() {
      _isAuthenticated = true;
    });
  }
});
}
```

Comment: `await Future.sync(()  async =>  _token = await _storage.read(key: 'TOKEN'));` this is not good

Answer (score 2):

You should do this instead

```dart
    Future<void> login() async {
      print('LOGGGGINNNNNNNNNNNN');
      print(await read('TOKEN'));
    }

    Future read(String storageName) async {
      return _storage.read(key: storageName);
    }
```

Since `read` returns a Future it will print what you currently see, so you need to wait its completion.

Comment: Okay, but I am using it for logging in. How can I wait to complete? Or there is any duration to make it take very short time?

Comment: You can `await` your call to `login()`